#  ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string

Tags: php

I am getting this error :

```
Warning: ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given in /home/sjrem/public_html/SIT104_3/order.php on line 29
An error occurred in parsing the sql string.
```

line 29: `$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);`

This is my entire code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body>



<?php

/* Set oracle user login and password info */
$dbuser = "sjrem"; /* your deakin login */
$dbpass = "password"; /* your oracle access password */
$db = "SSID";
$connect = OCILogon($dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

if (!$connect) {
echo "An error occurred connecting to the database";
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM purchase";
$query = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
OCIExecute($query);

/* check the sql statement for errors and if errors report them */
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);
//echo "SQL: $query<br>";
if(!$stmt) {
echo "An error occurred in parsing the sql string.\n";
exit;
}
OCIExecute($stmt);?>


<table>
<?PHP while (OCIFetch($query)) {

   $fg1 = OCIResult ($query , "ID" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>id: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg2 = OCIResult ($query , "FNAME" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>name</td><td>");  echo ($fg2);    echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg3 = OCIResult ($query , "LNAME" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>email: </td><td>");    echo ($fg3);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg4 = OCIResult ($query , "VIN" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Vin: </td><td>");    echo ($fg4);    echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg5 = OCIResult ($query , "EMAIL" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Email: </td><td>");   echo ($fg5);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg6 = OCIResult ($query , "UNIT" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Unit: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg7 = OCIResult ($query , "STREET" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Street: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg8 = OCIResult ($query , "SUBURB" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Suburb: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg9 = OCIResult ($query , "PCODE" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Post Code: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg10 = OCIResult ($query , "CREDIT" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Credit: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg11 = OCIResult ($query , "HOLDER" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Holder: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");
   $fg12 = OCIResult ($query , "EXPIRY" ) ;   echo("<tr><td>Expiry: </td><td>");  echo ($fg1);   echo ("</td> </tr>");


}





   ?>
</table>


</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Which part of `ociparse() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given` is unclear?

Comment: It seems that $query = OCIParse($connect, $sql); isn't returning what you expect it to return, so when you place $query in another OCIParse it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

`$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);`

`$query` is defined as: `$query = OCIParse($connect, $sql);`

You cannot `OCIParse` a resource, which `$query` is.

Maybe on line 29 you meant `$query = OCIParse($connect, $sql);`

Comment: got another one for ya haha 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443019/php-error-when-trying-to-submit-form-data-to-database-please-help

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $query);
```

should be:

```
$stmt = OCIParse($connect, $sql);
```

and remove the two lines preceeding it (why do you want to execute it twice?)